# Best Approach for syncing Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, azure, synchronization

Right now, our application only has one Web Site instance along with SQL Database deployed at Azure US datacenter. We are looking for deploying more Web Site instance at other datacenter such as APAC and Europe. There still be a local SQL Database for each of those web site instance. We would like end user could fail over to another instance if his registered instance is not available, such as if US web site instance is down, we could fail over user to Europe instance. With this, we would need to synchronize local SQL Database at all data centers, US, Europe and APAC.

So we are looking for what's best approach to implement the database synchronization here for Azure SQL Database. Here are what we found at this point:

- [Azure Data Sync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh456371.aspx), it looks like that it is the perfect choice since it is available right away at Azure Management Portal and it would be up and running with some simple configuration.  However there seems couple catches. The feature has been on preview about 2 years now ([see this link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync/) with the following quote from comment):

> SQL Data Sync has been in preview for over 2 years and the last update was December 2012. Has this been abandoned? Is this a technology we should encourage our clients to use? There absolutely needs to be an ability to synchronize data between a local SQL DB and Azure but Microsoft seems to have dropped this and I'm leery of putting a client on this only to find that the plug has been pulled. You owe it to your users to give us some information

I also saw the post [Azure data sync not syncing all databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900881/azure-data-sync-not-syncing-all-databases) at SO, it seems that this feature is a second class feature at Azure and MS doesn't really pay sufficient attention to it. So I am worried how good it is.

- [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992), it seems a more generic sync framework and more suitable for client and server sync instead of sync among server database. Plus it is not simple as above SQL Data Sync which is available just by configuration at Azure.

Any other suggestions on sql database sync at Azure? It would be really appreciated if you could share your experience here.

Thanks very much in advance for your insight.

**Update:**
Azure Data Sync is built upon using Microsoft Sync Framework: see [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1821.sql-data-sync-overview.aspx), the quote:

> Microsoft SQL Data Sync is a cloud-based data synchronization service built on the Microsoft Sync Framework technologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one is answering this question and I am going to do it myself. Based on some latest information, the Azure Data Sync is buggy and can not be used for production at this point. I guess that's the reason why it never moves out of preview even after around 2 years. There is no other good approach for handling Azure SQL Database sync at this point unless you want to build something yourself.

Answer (score 1):

you can use RedGate Data Compare to sync your Azuresql DB with your Local DB